# Which are the skills and digital skills related to Graphic Design that should be included in a resume?

Tags: resume, skillset

If I do graphic design and I want to include on my resume a list of digital skills that indicate my proficiency level, how would I put this, e.g.: is it better to write:

1) a list of softwares and/or programming languages, such as the following: -  "Photoshop - Illustrator - Inkscape..."

2) a list of "areas of application", like in the following: "Typography - Brochure - Social Media..."

Which (generic) **skills** and **digital skills**, related to **graphic design**, should be included in a **resume**?

Comment: Personally I feel portfolio matters way more when it comes to showcasing your skills. You can say that your Illustrator skills are 4/5, but what does that mean? What does it mean to you? What does that mean to the reader? It's a very abstract way to show what you can do... I'm not saying it's completely useless. Like If you list that you familiar with nothing but Adobe software and the company doesn't use any of them already, that's valuable information for them, but it's not an accurate representation of your skills as a designer. With a portfolio you can show exactly what you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have something which shows without any doubts you can do high quality creative work. No skill lists will do it nor certificates. Driver's license shows that you have proven to be able to drive. There's no such license for creative work. Show your own creations as well as designs which are based on specs you have received. If you have no real ordered and paid design works done, show imaginary ones, but done with your best effort.

It's useful to present work by work which tools were used and the usage principles. It's your skill list. If there were used some purchased or other "not your own" parts, you must reveal it exactly. Otherwise you will get stamped.